# image being affected by transition of another image's opacity transition

Tags: html, css

In the code below, there is an opacity transition which allows one image to fade out and reveal the one behind it. Overlaying both of these images is a logo image which is intended to remain in full view the full time of the transition, yet it does flicker out as the transition plays. (tested on chrome and firefox - seen on both)

How can i keep the logo constantly on top and in full opacity, while still having the underlying image fade work?

Please see the jsfiddle link at the bottom for a working example.

The HTML

```
<div>

  <img id="bloomtop"
    src="http://dev.kaizenauto.co/images/colorbloom.jpg">

  <img id="bloombottom"
       src="http://dev.kaizenauto.co/images/greybloom.jpg">

  <img class="img-responsive z99"
       src="http://dev.kaizenauto.co/images/drivenow.png">

</div>
```

The CSS

```
.z99 {
    z-index:99;
}

#bloomtop,
#bloombottom {
    width:100%;
    height:290px;
    margin-bottom:-290px;
    display:block;
    transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    z-index:1;
}


#bloombottom:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

All this in action in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ax3dwbyo/2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `position: relative` to your `.z99` div, like this:

```
.z99 {
     position: relative;
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```css
.z99 {
 z-index:99;
    position:relative;
}

#bloomtop,
#bloombottom {
 width:100%;
 height:290px;
 margin-bottom:-290px;
 display:block;
 transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
 z-index:1;
}


#bloombottom:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://dev.kaizenauto.co/images/colorbloom.jpg" id="bloomtop">
  <img src="http://dev.kaizenauto.co/images/greybloom.jpg" id="bloombottom">
  <img src="http://dev.kaizenauto.co/images/drivenow.png" class="img-responsive z99">
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ax3dwbyo/3/)**.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. If I wanted to learn why this works, what would i search for / read about?

Comment: @Zerp CSS Positioning and z-index.

Comment: You're welcome and you should read about CSS Positioning (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and the CSS z-index property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). Please mark my answer as correct so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: Check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). Pay attention to the fact that `z-index` is applied to _positioned elements_